# PHP UTF-8 questions - If I create a string in PHP... is it in UTF-8?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

In PHP, if I create a string like this:

```
$str = "bla bla here is my string";
```

Will I then be able to use the mbstring functions to operate on that string as UTF8?

```
// Will this work?
$str = mb_strlen($str);
```

Further, if I then have another string that I *know* is UTF-8 (say it was a POSTed form value, or a UTF-8 string from a database), can I then concatenate these two and not have any problems?

```
// What about this, will this work? 
$str = $str . $utf8_string_from_database;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First question: it depends on what exactly goes in the string.**

In PHP (up to PHP5, anyway), strings are just sequences of bytes.  There is no implied or explicit character set associated with them; that's something the programmer must keep track of.  So, if you only put valid UTF-8 bytes between the quotes (fairly easy if the file itself is encoded as UTF-8), then the string will be UTF-8, and you can safely use mb_strlen() on it.

Also, if you're using mbstring functions, you need to explicitly tell it what character set your string is, either with [mbstring.internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.internal-encoding) or as the last argument to any mbstring function.

**Second question: yes, with caveats.**

Two strings that are both independently valid UTF-8 can be safely byte-wise concatenated (like with PHP's `.` operator) and still be valid UTF-8.  However, you can never be sure, without doing some work yourself, that a POSTed string is valid UTF-8.  Database strings are a little easier, if you carefully set the connection character set, because most DBMSs will do any conversion for you.

Comment: About the second answer, this is why encoding validation/conversion must be part of any input validation routine. To that end, using a PHP stream input filter (iconv) will enable you to get UTF-8 strings into your application without having to use manual loops and MB/Iconv functions. Learning to get input from the php://input stream wrapper is the key.

Answer (score 3):

If your source code is in UTF-8, then the string is in UTF-8, if not — it’s not. Since your example string is english-only, it is valid UTF-8.

PHP doesn’t itself know about charsets. If you pass stuff to mb* function, it treats it as an UTF-8 string.

Concatenation must work fine no matter what, if I understand UTF-8 right :-) Just make sure *both* strings are UTF-8, otherwise you will get *strange* string as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your default_charset directive is set to UTF-8 before any of this execution occurs.

Either modify the php.ini directly or do it at runtime with

```
<?php

ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
```

Comment: All this does is control the headers sent to the client.  It doesn't actually affect anything about how PHP handles strings.

Comment: It does more than that.  Try executing urldecode('%C3%A9') with a default_charset of ISO-8859-1 and then again with a default_charset of UTF-8.  But you are correct, it has no bearing on how PHP treats strings at the bit level.

Comment: The ONLY reason you would see different results from that is because your browser is interpreting those bytes differently.  Like I said, it affects NOTHING about how PHP actually handles strings, WHATSOEVER.

Comment: I don't mean to start an argument here, but I think you're missing my point. I'm talking about how the string "%C3%A9" may be interpreted as a single 2-byte sequence, or two 1-byte sequences. This issue exists with or without a browser, although that's certainly where it occurs the most.

Comment: The question was about how PHP itself handles sequences of bytes.  Setting default_charset has no affect whatsoever on how PHP handles sequences of bytes.  I think we both agree on this.

Comment: Also, like I said, setting default_charset only affects the HTTP headers sent to the client.  "Browsers" (or anything that does HTTP) then are the only agents that setting default_charset will affect.  Execute your example on the command line and you'll see no difference.