# Remove accents - Replace accented letters by letters without accents with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace, diacritics, letters

str_replace does not replace accented letters by letters without accent. What's wrong with that?

This returns the expected result:

```
<?php
    $string = get_post_custom_values ("text");
    // Say get_post_custom_values ​​("text") equals "José José"
    $string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);

    echo $string [0];
    // Output "José-José"
?>
```

This does not work:

```
<?php
    $string = get_post_custom_values ("text");
    // Say get_post_custom_values ​​("text") equals "Joseph Joseph"
    $string = str_replace("é", "e", $string);

    echo $string [0];
    // Output "José José". Nothing has changed
?>
```

Note: Translated from the Portuguese language with GoogleTranslate.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728746/how-to-properly-handle-international-character-in-php-mysql-apache, "PHP" section.

Answer (score 1):

The easy, safe way to remove every accented letters is by using iconv :

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_CA.utf8"); // for instance
$output = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $input);
```

Your current problem is most likely caused by a different encoding.

Comment: The principle is that. Ok deceze and Vincent, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The character `é` as saved in your source code is not in the same *encoding* as the data you get back from `get_post_custom_values`. Encoding doesn't match → not recognized as the same character → not replaced.