# Slug function not working on my host - special characters removed

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a weird problem using a slug function to create a slug from a certain string.

```
function createSlug($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }
    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
    //strip extra slashes
    $clean = str_replace('/', '-', $clean);
    return $clean;
}

echo createSlug("Abbaye de Saint-Martin Cuvée de Noël.");
```

result: abbaye-de-saint-martin-cuve-de-nol

However, when I upload my script to another webspace of a different host, it works fine!
The output is what is should be: abbaye-de-saint-martin-cuvee-de-noel

Is there any explanation how this can happen? I just use the same script uploaded to my root folder of my host.

update:

iconv is enabled but it is not using UTF-8 and I do, but on my other hosts it works and the settings are exactly the same except for this: iconv library version 2.5

Info from phpinfo():
iconv

iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.11.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

Comment: `...de-nol` -- is this `nol` or `noel`?

Comment: Are you sure `iconv` is installed on your server?

Comment: it should be de-noel, the same as the original but lowercase and without accents.

Comment: It's likely a character set encoding issue.  Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728746/how-to-properly-handle-international-character-in-php-mysql-apache

Comment: Note also it's `cuvee` not `cuve`.

Comment: @John, indeed, alle the special characters are removed.  The problem isn't database related.

Comment: @Sébastien, is there a way I can check this? I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: Run `phpinfo();` in a separate file. You should find a section dedicated to iconv indicating "iconv support enabled".

Comment: @Sébastien, lol offcourse, should have known that, it is indeed enabled, I updated my question with extra info.

Comment: I tried your function on my test machine: it works. So try to output your `$clean` variable at every step to see where it breaks.

Comment: It is indeed the iconv function which goes wrong so it seems. Think I better contact my host :)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not have iconv on the server. If you cannot easily install it you can use character translation - there are a number of solutions floating around. Here's the one that WordPress uses with your code attached. The code comes from this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string)

```
<?php
function seems_utf8($str)
{
    $length = strlen($str);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
        elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
        elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
        else return false; # Does not match any model
        for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
            if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Converts all accent characters to ASCII characters.
 *
 * If there are no accent characters, then the string given is just returned.
 *
 * @param string $string Text that might have accent characters
 * @return string Filtered string with replaced "nice" characters.
 */
function remove_accents($string) {
    if ( !preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) )
        return $string;

    if (seems_utf8($string)) {
        $chars = array(
        // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
        chr(195).chr(128) => 'A', chr(195).chr(129) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(130) => 'A', chr(195).chr(131) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(132) => 'A', chr(195).chr(133) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(135) => 'C', chr(195).chr(136) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(137) => 'E', chr(195).chr(138) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(139) => 'E', chr(195).chr(140) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(141) => 'I', chr(195).chr(142) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(143) => 'I', chr(195).chr(145) => 'N',
        chr(195).chr(146) => 'O', chr(195).chr(147) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(148) => 'O', chr(195).chr(149) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(150) => 'O', chr(195).chr(153) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(154) => 'U', chr(195).chr(155) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(156) => 'U', chr(195).chr(157) => 'Y',
        chr(195).chr(159) => 's', chr(195).chr(160) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(161) => 'a', chr(195).chr(162) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(163) => 'a', chr(195).chr(164) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(165) => 'a', chr(195).chr(167) => 'c',
        chr(195).chr(168) => 'e', chr(195).chr(169) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(170) => 'e', chr(195).chr(171) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(172) => 'i', chr(195).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(174) => 'i', chr(195).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(177) => 'n', chr(195).chr(178) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(179) => 'o', chr(195).chr(180) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(181) => 'o', chr(195).chr(182) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(182) => 'o', chr(195).chr(185) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(186) => 'u', chr(195).chr(187) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(188) => 'u', chr(195).chr(189) => 'y',
        chr(195).chr(191) => 'y',
        // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
        chr(196).chr(128) => 'A', chr(196).chr(129) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(130) => 'A', chr(196).chr(131) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(132) => 'A', chr(196).chr(133) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(134) => 'C', chr(196).chr(135) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(136) => 'C', chr(196).chr(137) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(138) => 'C', chr(196).chr(139) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(140) => 'C', chr(196).chr(141) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(142) => 'D', chr(196).chr(143) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(144) => 'D', chr(196).chr(145) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(146) => 'E', chr(196).chr(147) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(148) => 'E', chr(196).chr(149) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(150) => 'E', chr(196).chr(151) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(152) => 'E', chr(196).chr(153) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(154) => 'E', chr(196).chr(155) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(156) => 'G', chr(196).chr(157) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(158) => 'G', chr(196).chr(159) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(160) => 'G', chr(196).chr(161) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(162) => 'G', chr(196).chr(163) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(164) => 'H', chr(196).chr(165) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(166) => 'H', chr(196).chr(167) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(168) => 'I', chr(196).chr(169) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(170) => 'I', chr(196).chr(171) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(172) => 'I', chr(196).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(174) => 'I', chr(196).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(176) => 'I', chr(196).chr(177) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(178) => 'IJ',chr(196).chr(179) => 'ij',
        chr(196).chr(180) => 'J', chr(196).chr(181) => 'j',
        chr(196).chr(182) => 'K', chr(196).chr(183) => 'k',
        chr(196).chr(184) => 'k', chr(196).chr(185) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(186) => 'l', chr(196).chr(187) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(188) => 'l', chr(196).chr(189) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(190) => 'l', chr(196).chr(191) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(128) => 'l', chr(197).chr(129) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(130) => 'l', chr(197).chr(131) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(132) => 'n', chr(197).chr(133) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(134) => 'n', chr(197).chr(135) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(136) => 'n', chr(197).chr(137) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(138) => 'n', chr(197).chr(139) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(140) => 'O', chr(197).chr(141) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(142) => 'O', chr(197).chr(143) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(144) => 'O', chr(197).chr(145) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE',chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe',
        chr(197).chr(148) => 'R',chr(197).chr(149) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(150) => 'R',chr(197).chr(151) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(152) => 'R',chr(197).chr(153) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(154) => 'S',chr(197).chr(155) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(156) => 'S',chr(197).chr(157) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(158) => 'S',chr(197).chr(159) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(161) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(162) => 'T', chr(197).chr(163) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(164) => 'T', chr(197).chr(165) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(166) => 'T', chr(197).chr(167) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(168) => 'U', chr(197).chr(169) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(170) => 'U', chr(197).chr(171) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(172) => 'U', chr(197).chr(173) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(174) => 'U', chr(197).chr(175) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(176) => 'U', chr(197).chr(177) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(178) => 'U', chr(197).chr(179) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(180) => 'W', chr(197).chr(181) => 'w',
        chr(197).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(183) => 'y',
        chr(197).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(185) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(186) => 'z', chr(197).chr(187) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(188) => 'z', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(197).chr(191) => 's',
        // Euro Sign
        chr(226).chr(130).chr(172) => 'E',
        // GBP (Pound) Sign
        chr(194).chr(163) => '');

        $string = strtr($string, $chars);
    } else {
        // Assume ISO-8859-1 if not UTF-8
        $chars['in'] = chr(128).chr(131).chr(138).chr(142).chr(154).chr(158)
            .chr(159).chr(162).chr(165).chr(181).chr(192).chr(193).chr(194)
            .chr(195).chr(196).chr(197).chr(199).chr(200).chr(201).chr(202)
            .chr(203).chr(204).chr(205).chr(206).chr(207).chr(209).chr(210)
            .chr(211).chr(212).chr(213).chr(214).chr(216).chr(217).chr(218)
            .chr(219).chr(220).chr(221).chr(224).chr(225).chr(226).chr(227)
            .chr(228).chr(229).chr(231).chr(232).chr(233).chr(234).chr(235)
            .chr(236).chr(237).chr(238).chr(239).chr(241).chr(242).chr(243)
            .chr(244).chr(245).chr(246).chr(248).chr(249).chr(250).chr(251)
            .chr(252).chr(253).chr(255);

        $chars['out'] = "EfSZszYcYuAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy";

        $string = strtr($string, $chars['in'], $chars['out']);
        $double_chars['in'] = array(chr(140), chr(156), chr(198), chr(208), chr(222), chr(223), chr(230), chr(240), chr(254));
        $double_chars['out'] = array('OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th');
        $string = str_replace($double_chars['in'], $double_chars['out'], $string);
    }

    return $string;
}


function createSlug($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }
    //$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = remove_accents($str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
    //strip extra slashes
    $clean = str_replace('/', '-', $clean);
    return $clean;
}

echo createSlug("Abbaye de Saint-Martin Cuvée de Noël.");
?>
```

Comment: Thx, butICONV is installed on the server, that's the weirdness. I can use some alternative functions but I would like to know what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the slug function I use for French UTF-8 text. It doesn't rely on `iconv` because I used it a long time ago on a shared hosting with no chance to install it.

Since your text is French this might help you. I have commented the function but the general idea is:

- make a list of characters that I absolutely want to translit
- make a corresponding list of url-safe ascii characters.
- all remaining unrecognized characters are eliminated via a regex

Additionnally you can specify the word separator, you can choose to allow uppercase characters, all HTML tags are removed and all trailing and doubled word separators are removed.

```
function createSlug( $str = '', $allowUppercase = 0, $separator = '-' )
{
    // Illegal chars contains non-French characters that my be encountered in French text with names of foreign authors
    $illegal = array( ' ', ' ', '#160;', '&amp;', '—', '–', '\'', '/', ',', '&', '...', '?', '!', '(', ')', '&#160;', '…', '’', '.', ':', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ç', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ÿ', 'ñ', 'œ', 'æ', '%', '"' );
    $illegalUc = array( 'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ç', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ÿ', 'Ñ', 'Œ', 'Æ' );

    // Corresponding list of chaaracters/words to replace illegal chars
    $legal = array( $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, $separator, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'c', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'n', 'oe', 'ae', $separator.'pourcent'.$separator, $separator );
    $legalUc = array( 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 'N', 'OE', 'AE' );

    $str = strip_tags( $str ); // remove all HTML tags

    if( $allowUppercase )
    {
        $illegal = array_merge( $illegal, $illegalUc );
        $legal = array_merge( $legal, $legalUc );
    }

    if( !$allowUppercase )
    {
        $str = mb_strtolower( $str, 'UTF-8' );
    }
    $str = str_replace( $illegal, $legal, $str ); // The main translit using our 2 lists

    // Strip all other illegal characters
    $pattern = '/[^A-Za-z0-9]/ui'; // Unicode, case insensitive

    $str = preg_replace( $pattern, $separator, $str );

    // Reduce all double separators to single ones
    while( ( strpos( $str, $separator.$separator ) !== false ) )
    {
        $str = str_replace( $separator.$separator, $separator, $str );
    }

    // Remove any trailing separator
    $str = ltrim( $str, $separator );
    $str = rtrim( $str, $separator );

    return $str; // the string is returned with or without changes
}
```

Comment: Thx, nice function, I have done something similar now to filter the special characters but I'm still curious why my current script isn't working while ICONV is configured on the server.

Comment: Odd. And I assume that PHP is configured to use it? phpinfo();