# Encoding troubles converting MySQL to Mongo with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, encoding, utf-8

I've been having a lot of encoding troubles with PHP/Mongo in general.

Right now, I'm in the process of converting some data from MySQL to Mongo. I have a string that contains a `é`, but when I try to encode it to UFT-8 (via `mb_convert_encoding`, `uft8_encode`), it turns into `Ã©`. I'm sure other strings also contain other accented characters.

I've tried `mb_detect_encoding`, which told me the string is UTF-8, but when I do `mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8')`, it returns false.

Basically, I have no idea what's wrong. This is on a page that is just a PHP script, no HTML. Any advice to this problem, or in general maintaining character encoding when inserting into Mongo?

Here is the script in question: https://plnkr.co/edit/eAkLxfklzLNCsZTBPKsX

The MySQL table is using a MyISAM engine, charset utf8, collation utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: You're saying it's 'on a page that is just a PHP script' however it is still consumed by the browser? Have you checked your HTML content descriptors?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not totally sure what you mean. I did set `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` at the top.

Comment: Ok, can you show us your PHP script? The other issue might be the way Mongo is set up vs MySQL.

Comment: Added the script and MySQL table settings

Comment: So the `Ã©` is proper UTF encoding as read by a normal text reader - any extended ASCII characters are converted to two bytes instead of the one byte `é`. I don't think the export from MySQL is incorrect - it contains the correct UTF-8 values. It must be your MongoDB import. I don't actually see where you initialise your mongo database in the PHP script - perhaps you need to explicitly specify your encoding parameters there?

Comment: When someone enter's an accented character in a form (on pages, I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` set), it shows up in mongo as an accented character. As mentioned, I've been having trouble with encoding. When I store the `Ã©` into Mongo, and then try to display with PHP (using something like `utf8_decode`), it garbles entirely. Not sure what to do anymore.

Comment: Perhaps your only mistake is the text/plain - according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682409/reading-utf-8-content-from-mysql-table it should be text/html? Otherwise I'm stumped, sorry. (Awesome name btw ;D)

Comment: What do you mean you have a string that contains "é"? Where is this string? Is it in your php file? Is it in a form on a html page that you post? Anyway, give us some details. In what encoding it is? Why not utf8? (you say you want to convert it to utf8, so I suppose it's not in utf8 :)

Comment: Mr Rho: I've tried as text/plain, text/html, and without that entirely, no luck. Gavriel, as stated in the question, I'm trying to convert MySQL to Mongo. The string is from MySQL. And as the question states, `mb_detect_encoding` says its UFT-8 but `mb_check_encoding` says it's not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

- Do not use the mysql_* API; change to mysqli_*
- Do not use any mb or utf8 encode/decode routines; they merely hide the 'proper' solution.
- Right after connecting to mysql, do `SET NAMES utf8`.
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- verify that the table/columns are `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4)

`Ã©` is the Mojibake for `é`.  It usually indicates a mismatch of `latin1` settings and `utf8` settings.

If using PDO:   `$db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF8', $user, $pwd);` *or* execute `SET NAMES utf8`.

Comment: I'm not using the mysql_* API; using PDO. I'll try `SET NAMES utf8` with it.

Comment: I added a note about PDO.

Comment: As noted above, all the columns are utf8_unicode_ci, so I'm gonna try the charset tomorrow at work.