# UTF-8 issue when using hibernate to store/retrieve JSON data from MySql

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate

In my database table, there is a column named json_data, which is a JSON data type field. The according field in the entity class is `@Column(name="json_data")
String jsonData;`.

Some data with UTF-8 characters are saved using entity.save() into database(something like \u2202). When it's retrieved, the encoding is wrong, and I got character \u0113.

My question is: what needs to be done in order to save/retrieve the JSON data type data from MySql using hibernate

Comment: See if this post helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682409/reading-utf-8-content-from-mysql-table

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
ObjectMapper objMap=new ObjectMapper();
...
String jsonData = resultSet.getString("json_data");
Employee employee= (Employee) objMap.readValue(jsonData, Employee.class);
//replace Employee with your json java mapper class name
...
```