# Using UTF-8 for Chinese characters and pinyin not working

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to output Chinese characters and Pinyin from my Game.php file.

In my Game.HTML file, just using `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` works fine.

But in my Game.PHP file, it does not. So I tried following these to get it to work:

1) [How to best configure PHP to handle a UTF-8 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website)

2) [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

At the top of my Game.PHP file, I've included this in the `<head>` portion of the HTML... and I've added the specified `default_charset` to my php.ini file, and the `AddDefaultCharset` to my Apache file. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to put Chinese characters to the editor? Do you send a header like this? header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: @zaynetro yes I'm trying to put them in the editor. I sent the header but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried in sublime on ubuntu and I didn't have any problems. http://i.imgur.com/86B5TVz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the PHP utf8_encode() function. Try $character = utf8_encode(put your character here) and be sure to use single or double quotes around the character.

In NotePAD++

Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/ Open Save Directory

Under New Document Encoding -> check UTF8 without BOM

Comment: In my editor (Notepad++), it comes out as `$character = utf8_encode('Äã');`