# How to set php to utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am having problems with my code setting the utf-8

I have set

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

I also tried

`ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');`

I have not tried

`$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

as I am not even connecting to the sql database. I have five files

`core.php` `l18n.php` `l18n_js.php` `lang.php` and `response_class.php`

Core calls `l18n.php` and `response_class.php`

Then we have lang.php which is a dummy webpage with the meta charset already set to utf-8 and it calls to `l18n_js.php` and it has `core.php` included with it which then returns the correct language file.

I am telling you what is going on as to ask do I need to set the header on each of the php files, as well as `ini_set` I am having so much difficulty making sure it is encoded to utf-8 and not show characters like `Ã³ Ã©l te h` all messed up

Comment: did you make sure your db tables are utf-8 as well? You need to ensure the ENTIRE rendering pipeline is utf-8. client->server->mysql->table->php->client

Comment: but why when I don't even call the sql db at all what so ever...?

Comment: well, where's this text coming from? are you sure it's utf-8? what about utf-16?

Comment: It's coming from response_class.php

Comment: which means nothing to us. that's like saying "it comes from planet earth"

Comment: lol. It's a php object class. functions with arrays. I just tested the sql db and it responded with `Current character set: utf8`

Comment: here see what is happend -->  http://minjs.site88.net/l18n_js.php?lang=es  you can change the lang to `en` to see the english version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52449/discussion-between-easybb-and-marc-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please see this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website) for how to configure PHP to handle UTF-8. If it still doesn't work, anywhere that you expect UTF-8 output from your database, use

```
htmlentities($foobar, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

The last parameter is optional if you are running PHP >= 5.4.0, but I always include it for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I've done all of that except the php.ini since I don't have one specifically. Still nothing- but I can try the entities one

Comment: With the htmlentities I got this: `&#039;no se puede&#039;:{` which is way wrong... I should mention that in the `l18n_js.php` I have the header as `header("content-type: application/x-javascript");`

Comment: nevermind it's coming out perfectly fine when I use it as an actual js file and not when I go to the js file itself it's weird but whatever. Sorry guys