# PHP iconv Special Character Conversion

Tags: php

I have a problem converting the UTF-8 chars to the plain text. Some of them work while some give : `?`

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', "Žluťoøučký kůň")
```

Outputs:

```
Zluto?ucky kun
```

The `ø` is `?`. My Php file is UTF-8 and there is no problem with encoding.

Any Ideas why?

> Trying to run in Apache. Works fine when using through terminal `php` compiling

Comment: I am not very sure but do you not have to try setting locale? Also, adding `PHP_EOL` at the end?

Comment: Tried that. If that works in your case, mind posting an answer?

Comment: How are you running this script? From a browser? If I run `php -r "echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Žluťoøučký kůň');"` in my command line, I get the output `Zlutooeucky kun`.

Comment: @xathien on a `.php` file

Comment: Specifically, are you executing from the command line (somewhat like I did), or are you running it through a Webserver, e.g. Apache?

Comment: @xathien. Apache (Tried both on Mac an Linux). But, should that make a difference? **I got "o" using php commands, but I need this on a website. Is this some part of apache configuration?**

Comment: Check the request headers that are returning from Apache. Odds are, either Apache is trying to return it in ISO format, or your browser is displaying it wrong. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website) to see if it helps.