# How to convert my php files to utf8?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, utf-8

I am developing an Android app which is based on a custom soft keyboard and
contains different languages.

How do I convert these php files to utf8?

**create_product.php**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**get_all_products.php**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["description"] = $row["description"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];



        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**get_product_detail.php**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
            $product["name"] = $result["name"];
            $product["price"] = $result["price"];
            $product["description"] = $result["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?></body></html>
```

**update_product.php**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<?php

/*
 * Following code will update a product information
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name = '$name', price = '$price', description = '$description' WHERE pid = $pid");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully updated.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
</body></html>
```

**delete_product.php**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<?php

/*
 * Following code will delete a product from table
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");

    // check if row deleted or not
    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully deleted";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?></body></html>
```

**JSONparser.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: So is the encoding wrong? Are some of the chars not displayed properly?

Comment: yes @sitilge its shows question marks (??????) in wamp server

Comment: are values in DB stored correctly?

Comment: yes @sitilge its stored correctly and working fine in english keyboard but not in other language

Comment: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));` or since Java 7:

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: Is the solution of @moskito-x working?

Comment: @moskito-x still not working i have also tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website
but still same "????"

Comment: @sitilge its not workin

Comment: I still don't understand: is the response from server valid **or** the chars are displayed wrong on the android device?

Comment: @sitilge response from server is valid and displaying chars fine when i typed in English but when i typed in other language like urdu/hindi it displayed question marks.

Comment: Are they stored correctly in database?

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is an encoding error like you say, you can use Notepad++ (which if you don't have it, get it). In the settings of the file, you would go to:

**Encoding > Encode in UTF-8 (without BOM)** at the top of the page.

This is what I use, so if it is an encoding error, this would fix it.