# How to replace decoded Non-breakable space (nbsp)

Tags: php, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

Assuming I have a sting which is `"a s d d"` and `htmlentities` turns it into
`"a&nbsp;s&nbsp;d&nbsp;d"`.

How to replace (using preg_replace) it without encoding it to entities?

I tried `preg_replace('/[\xa0]/', '', $string);`, but it's not working. I'm trying to remove those special characters from my string as I don't need them

What are possibilities beyond regexp?

Edit
String I want to parse: http://pastebin.com/raw/7eNT9sZr
with function `preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "[##]", $text)`
for later `implode("</p><p>", explode("[##]", $text))`

My question is not exactly "how" to do this (since I could encode entities, remove entities i don't need and decode entities). But how to remove those with just str_replace or preg_replace.

Comment: `htmlentities` is prevention against xss. If you want to render in browser, the  &nbsp will be evaluated as space only. If not then there is no use of the function

Comment: do you want to replace the spaces or the `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @georoot htmlentities prevents bad HTML output (ie. it ensures that information is emitted, not data), XSS is just maliciously crafted bad data.

Comment: `$string` == `a s d d` or `a&nbsp;s&nbsp;d&nbsp;d`?

Comment: `htmlentities("a s d d")` outputs `"a&nbsp;s&nbsp;d&nbsp;d"`

Comment: @user2864740 exactly my point. You use `htmlentities` if you want to render in browser in which case &nbsp doesn't make any difference. If you don't want to render in browser there is no use of the function

Comment: @georoot The information in HTML of " " and "&nbsp;" is different. One is a space. One is a non-breaking space. Only a non-breaking space is encoded as "&nbsp;", not a normal space.

Comment: It's not for displaying, its for storing in database only. Only solution i can come up with atm is htmlenitities > str_replace > entities_decode chain

Comment: @Grzegorz Use SQL parameterized queries for "storing to the database". In any case the input data *already contains* a not-a-normal-space.

Comment: @Grzegorz what is the point of using perl expressions? Why not to use str_replace in this case?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/7eNT9sZr Here is string I want to make into html. Replace multiple \r\n (which are divided by \xa0) and make pretty html.

Comment: I think he is looking for a way to remove the non-breaking spaces from the string WITHOUT turning them into HTML entities first.

Comment: In what encoding is your string? Is it UTF-8? If yes, I would say that non-breakable space is `0xc2a0` there.

Comment: It's utf8. Also tried `\xc2a0` nothing is working and I'm wondering **WHY**. I want to know how it works, not how to do this :)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

### Problem Explanation

The reason why it's not working is that you are specifying the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) incorrectly.

The proper code for the non-breaking space in the UTF-8 encoding is [`0xC2A0`](https://codepoints.net/U+00A0), it consists of two bytes - `0xC2` (`194`) and `0xA0` (`160`), so technically, you're specifying only the half of the character's code.

### A Bit of Theory

Legacy character encodings were using the constant number of bits to encode every character in their set. For example, the original [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) was using 7 bits per character, extended ASCII 8 bits.

The UTF-8 encoding is so-called *variable width character encoding*, which means that the number of bits used to represent individual characters is variable, in the case of UTF-8, character codes consist of one up to four (8 bit) bytes (octets). In general, similarly to the *Huffman coding*, more frequently used characters have shorter codes while more rare characters have longer codes. That helps reduce the data size of the average text.

### Solution

You can replace all occurences of the UTF-8 non-breaking space in text using a simple (and fast) `str_replace` or using a more flexible regular expression, depending on your needs:

```
// faster solution
$regular_spaces = str_replace("\xc2\xa0", ' ', $original_string);

// more flexible solution
$regular_spaces = preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/', ' ', $original_string);
```

### Notes

Note that **in case of [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), you have to use double quotes (`"`) to enclose the search string** because *it doesn't understand the textual representation of character codes* so it needs those codes to be converted into actual characters first. That's made automatically by PHP because strings enclosed in double quotes are being processed and special sequences (e.g. newline character `\n`, textual representation of character codes, etc.) are replaced by actual characters (e.g. `0x0A` for `\n` in UTF-8) before the string value is being used.

In contrast, the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function itself *understands the textual representation of character codes* so you don't need PHP to convert them into actual characters and you can **use apostrophes (single quotes, `'`) to enclose the search string** in this case.

Comment: Note that `str_replace()` will work as well and is much faster.

Comment: @simon Thank you, you're right. Added to my answer.

Comment: I had no idea I have to write `\xc2\xa0` and wrote `\xc2a0`... my fail. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe could you tell me how to replace it in group? `preg_replace('/[\x0E-\x1f]/', '', $string);`?

Comment: @Grzegorz I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean how to say that the codes in square brackets (`[\xc2\xa0]`) are a single character and not two?

Comment: Encodings are not my strong point (utf8). For example I have `preg_replace('/[\x0E-\x1F\xc2\xa0]/', '', $string);` it would replace either `\xc2` and `\xa0` how to include it in regex so it only replaces `\xc2\xa0` and leaves `\xc2` intact?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Any idea? :P

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about that. Did you solve it already? If not, you can probably create a new question to address that.

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan Is it possible to trim both these `\xc2\xa0` and space with the same `trim` function? like `trim($str, "\xC2\xA0")` or is there any way to do like that?

Comment: This was very helpful. However, in an ASCII file it's just \xA0. In Excel I was able to locate this character by searching for \xC2\xA0 but when I saved the file to CSV I found the character by searching for \xA0.

Answer (score 26):

Sanitize [every type of white spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode).

```
preg_replace("/\s+/u", " ", $str);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40264711/635364

FYI, PHP Sanitization [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) has no filter about these white spaces.

Comment: This is definitely the best option and should be the selected answer.

Comment: The only answer that worked for me!

Comment: This solution is also the most flexible – I had to `trim()` a string and non breakable spaces were not removed, so rather than replacing and then trimming I did a simple `preg_replace("/^\s+|\s+$/u", "", $str)`.

Comment: AFAICS, this will replace all consequent whitespace into one. You may need to remove the `+` after `\s` to keep the number of spaces the same. Also, I'm not sure about this, but this may remove the line breaks too.

Answer (score 0):

Select the right charset of your string

```
$yourCharset='UTF-8'; // or 'ISO8859-1', or...
```

Use the return value of `html_entity_decode` to replace.

```
$string=str_replace(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;',ENT_COMPAT,$yourCharset),' ',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

just `preg_replace('/\s/', ' ',$string)` works for me fine