Replace non-breaking space between words
I'm trying with PHP to get rid of annoying non-breaking spaces between words that CKEditor + Chrome keep adding.
Like
Some text here&nbsp;and more text here

But it's been a while and regex is confusing my brain
Was trying something like:
preg_replace('/(\S)(&nbsp;)(\S)/', "$1 $3", $text);

To capture the before and after and just use a blank space, but it does nothing.
Help please?

What is the purpose of checking for non-whitespace chars? Why not $text = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text)?

"but it does nothing." - what are you talking about? https://3v4l.org/aY9qP - doesn't look like it "did nothing" to me?

Ah, i figured out the issue this was the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724830/1741251
