# Black diamonds with question marks on fresh LAMP server

Tags: php, encoding, phpmyadmin, lamp

The black squares even happen in phpMyAdmin - not when looking at text in  tables, but actually in the phpMyAdmin strings like "Loading...", suggesting this is a low-level configuration problem.

I've read about this here and elsewhere and tried several remedies, all to no effect.

It's happening on a new VPS: Debian/Apache 2.4.10/MySQL 5.6/php 7.

```
Server connection collation: utf_general_ci
php_info() shows default_charset: UTF-8
php version is 7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.1
page headers show Content-Type text/html; charset=iso-utf-8
there is no meta charset in the HTML
Apache mime module is active
```

The squares are occurring for characters like ellipsis, emdash, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you are not supporting utf8 characters, take a look at your Apache setup as described here:

[How to best configure PHP to handle a UTF-8 website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610475/1491675)

Comment: I followed that, no joy. Thanks for your suggestion Chris.