# Wrong encoding with PHP

Tags: php, nginx, encoding, utf-8, iconv

Production server (This is the correct behaviour)

```
>>> $str = "àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý";
=> "àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý"
>>> strtoupper($str);
=> "àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý"
>>> mb_strtoupper($str);
=> "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ"
```

New local environment

```
>>> $str = "àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý";
=> "àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý</string>"
>>> strtoupper($str);
=> "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ</string>"
>>> mb_strtoupper($str);
=> "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ</string>"
```

I can't find anything on the internet regarding this `</string>` at the end of the variable.

It also fails with `iconv` function

Production server

```
>>> iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'áè');
=> "ae"
```

New local environment

```
>>> iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'áè');
=> "'a`e"
```

I followed the instructions regarding `PHP` found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website/1610475#1610475) but no luck, I ignored `MySQL` since I'm not using it, I also ignored the Apache one since I have Nginx.

I started to think it's because mbstring extension but can't find anything related with that.

EDIT: It's not a duplicate [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) because it's not an issue with MySQL and I already tried the solutions exposed there. It's not a matter of get an alternative for `iconv` but to fix the environment to do the same as Production.