# Laravel request returning unicode replacement character in array value

Tags: php, json, laravel, unicode, request

I'm sending a `json` request (on diffrent platforms) and can't getting the values with `$request->all()` function, as i expected. I have to validate `name` parameter with `regex:/^[\p{L}]+$/` so it is not the case that i want. I must pass the `request` values to the `Validator` without any replacement.

**Json Request example** :

```
{
  "name": "guvuvıvıvöö",
  "surname": "bbbbbbbbbbbb",
  "phone": "+905544002218",
  "password": "123123123",
  "password_confirmation": "123123123",
  "dob": "2017-04-18",
  "gender": "1",
  "confirmationKey" : null
}
```

**`$request->all()` function returns**

```
array (size=8)
'name' => string 'guvuvvivÃ¶Ã¶' (length=12)
'surname' => string 'bbbbbbbbbbbb' (length=12)
'phone' => string '+905544002218' (length=13)
'password' => string '123123123' (length=9)
'password_confirmation' => string '123123123' (length=9)
'dob' => string '2017-04-18' (length=10)
'gender' => string '1' (length=1)
'confirmationKey' => null
```

Hope you can help me. if you want, i can share more code or information..

Comment: Are you using Laravel Valet? I have a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730617/wrong-encoding-with-php Can you try the methods I tried? You can use `php artisan tinker` for try it

Comment: I'm using Laravel with homestad not Valet. Should i try `php artisan tinker` still ?

Comment: How is the JSON being generated?

Comment: It doesn't matter how it is being generated because even if i manually create a json and send it with postman to the service. it is giving the same result.

Comment: Yeah try that tinker commands from inside Homestead