# Full utf-8 compliance for a php web app?

Tags: php, unicode, localization

I'm writing a small web app that will receive and parse tab-delimited text files from users. Those files will either be uploaded via a `textarea` or a `multipart/form-data` form.  Those files will be in a variety of charsets, including Asian and the like.  In consequence I am trying to use utf-8 throughout the app.

The site is entirely (as far as I know) in UTF-8:

- Each php file is saved in utf-8 encoding;
- I have added `default_charset = "utf-8"` in my `php.ini` file;
- The HTML header contains the required utf-8 mentions:

  ```
  header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  ...
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  ...
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  ```
- The `textarea` forms contain the `accept-charset="UTF-8"` tag.
- The db is collated in utf-8;
- Each connection to the db includes the option `1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'`.

Now, I just discovered that I needed to set `mb_regex_encoding` to utf-8 manually for one of my parsing function to work (I use `mb_split()` to identify & replace tabs and new lines).  So ...

What else do I need to do to make sure my site is once and for all utf-8 throughout?  In particular, are there any other encoding function I should set, such as `mb_internal_encoding()`, and if so where in the code should I do that (e.g., at the start of the `index.php` file?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317152

Comment: @Vague - yes, it mentions neither `mb_regex_encoding` nor `mb_internal_encoding`.

Comment: @JDelage: PCRE functions do with UTF-8 as well, just FYI. And don't use `SET NAMES utf8`, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: @hakre - Is that something I can use with PDO?  My entire db interactions are PDO based.

Comment: @JDelage: Please see [PHP PDO: charset, set names?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4361459/367456)

Comment: @hakre - Thanks, good resource, unfortunately I use v.5.3.0, and this solution only works for version >=5.3.6.

Comment: @JDelage: Time for upgrade ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two more things;

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

...as early as possible in the PHP script, and

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
```

...to set the connection charset, if you're using MySql. For PDO, you can specify it with the [connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4361459/367456):

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"
```

Comment: Reg. `mb_internal_encoding()`, should I do that before or after `session_start()`?

Comment: @JDelage: `mb_...` is not related to `session_start` if you don't use serialized objects that use `mb_...` function while deserializing.

Comment: You should set the internal encoding for multibyte string manipulation functions **before** you try to manipulate any multibyte strings. I don't think session_start() implies any string manipulation, so I wouldn't use that as a cursor.

Comment: I'm only using that as the first thing that is read by the script.  My code starts with `require_once(objects in session);` and then `session_start()`.

Comment: Wow, both question and 'my' answer have been edited so much here that I hardly recognize them anymore...